# Problemas com a conexão JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

Bom dia prezados.
Estou tendo problemas com jdbc. 
A conexão com o banco é feita mas, não traz nada com o select.
O console do eclipse me reportou alguns problemas, como:
Faltava a lib do proto-buf-java, coloquei a dependência no maven.
Estou usando o BD mysql, e coloquei a versão mais nova do conector.
Coloquei o método getRow, para indicar o número de linhas que ele está pegando e reotornou zero.
Primeiro colocarei  classe de conexão.

```
protected Connection getConnection() throws Exception,SQLException{
    String driverName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cne) {
            System.out.println("Driver não encontrado");
        }
        try{                        
                    //Properties props = getProp();

                       String url = "jdbc:mysql://500.500.500.100:3306/sgbdmysql";
                       String usuario = "user";
                       String senha = "password";
                     //Conecta usando a URL, usuario e senha
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);
                    System.out.println(conn);
                    return conn;
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            throw e;
        }



    }
Classse DAO

public Date getDataOperacao()throws Exception,SQLException{
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        Date dta = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            //Teste Mau - sucedido
            String str = "SELECT dataoperacao FROM cimentacao_grafico WHERE well_name LIKE 'well3%' \n" + 
                    " ORDER BY idgrafico DESC LIMIT 1";
            //stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT dataoperacao FROM cimentacao_grafico WHERE well_name LIKE 'well3%' \n" + 
            //      " ORDER BY idgrafico DESC LIMIT 1");
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cimentacao_hkloadcritico");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs.getRow());
            if (rs.getRow() == 0) {
                dta = new Date();
            } else {
                dta = rs.getDate("dataoperacao");
            }

        }finally {
            if(stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
        return dta;
    }
```

Comment: Vê para mim as propriedades `isClosed` e `isValid` da conexão.

Comment: A tabela `cimentacao_hkloadcritico` tem registros?

Comment: Tem sim, 4 registros pra ser mais exato.

Comment: Você não edita o título para marcar como "resolvido". Você aceita a resposta que, de fato, resolveu o seu problema. Na inexistência de tal, crie a sua própria resposta e a aceite

Comment: E como faz pra aceitar a resposta que me deram? Procurei algum lugar pra fazer isso e não encontrei. Tem muito tempo que não uso stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja confundindo o objetivo do método `getRow()`, retirando o trecho da [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow()):

```
Retrieves the current row number. The first row is number 1, the second number 2, and so on.
```

Lembrando que a **posição inicial** do `ResultSet` é sempre **0 (zero)**, se você simplesmente consultar, e chamar o método `getRow()` ele irá lhe retornar **0 (zero)**.

Caso a lógica que você esteja querendo é verificar se houveram resultados, e se não houveram retornar a data atual, talvez o que você deseje fazer é o seguinte:

```
if( rs.next() ) { // Verifica se existe um próximo registro no ResultSet
    dta = rs.getDate("dataoperacao");
} else {
    dta = new Date();
}
```

O método `rs.next()` irá andar no `ResultSet`, e caso exista um registro irá retornar `true`.

Caso você chame o `getRow()` após o `rs.next()`, você receberá como resultado **1 (um)**, visto que você está na primeira linha do `ResultSet`.

Aplicando os métodos `ResultSet.get...()` irá então lhe retornar o valor da linha em que você está no momento.

Lembrando que o `if( rs.next() )` irá só verificar se existe **uma próxima linha** como resultado, se você deseja iterar sobre várias linhas sugiro utilizar o `while( rs.next() )`, porém ajustando sua condição quando não houver resultados.

---

Esqueci de mencionar, caso você queira saber a quantidade total de registros no seu `ResultSet`, então você continuaria a utilizar o `getRow()` mas da seguinte forma:

```
if( rs.last() ) {
    System.out.println("Total de linhas: " + rs.getRow());
    rs.beforeFirst(); // Retorna a posição do ResultSet para posição original (0)
}
```

Comment: Realmente, me enganei com o uso do getRow. Tanto que, descobri que ele mascarou que o eu tinha feito anteriormente, talvez tivesse reolvido. Mas, por desencargo de consciência, eu coloquei o código que vc sugeriu e deu certo. Muito obrgado mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta :)